# Specify Perl signal handler using the number, not the name

Tags: perl, signals, handler

I want to specify a signal handler in Perl, but using the number, not the name.  Is this possible in a succinct way?  The lack of symmetry with kill particularly sticks out.  For example, instead of

```
$SIG{USR2} = \&myhandler;
```

I'd like to say

```
$SIG{12} = \&myhandler;
```

The best I have at the moment is to "use Config" and poke around in $Config{sig_name}, based on the code in perldoc perlipc. This is verbose and seems needlessly complicated.

Rationale: I've wanted this in two cases recently.

1: I'm being started by a buggy parent process who incorrectly sets signals I care about to ignore, and I want to just reset everything to default.  eg http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=679630  The goal would be something simple and brute force like:

```
foreach my $i (1..32) { $SIG{$i} = 'DEFAULT'; }
```

2: I'm writing a thin, as-invisible-as-possible wrapper script.  If the program I'm wrapping exits with a signal, I want to exit with that same signal.  However, I capture a few signals, so I need to clear my own signal handler to ensure i actually exit instead of entering my signal handler.   My goal is to write something brief like this:

```
$ret = system("./other-program");
$SIG{$ret & 127} = 'DEFAULT';
kill $ret & 127, $$;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question:

```
use Config qw( %Config );

my @sig_name_by_num;
@sig_name_by_num[ split(' ', $Config{sig_num}) ] = split(' ', $Config{sig_name});

$SIG{$sig_name_by_num[12]} = \&handler;
```

---

Second question:

```
use Config qw( %Config );

$SIG{$_} = 'DEFAULT' for split ' ', $Config{sig_name};
```

-or-

```
$SIG{$_} = 'DEFAULT' for keys %SIG;
```

-or-

```
$_ = 'DEFAULT' for values %SIG;
```

---

Third question

```
use Config qw( %Config );

my @sig_name_by_num;
@sig_name_by_num[ split(' ', $Config{sig_num}) ] = split(' ', $Config{sig_name});

my $sig_num = $? & 0x7F;
$SIG{$sig_name_by_num[$sig_num]} = 'DEFAULT';
kill($sig_num => $$);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to set all signals at once, you don't need to know their numbers:

```
$SIG{$_} = 'DEFAULT' for keys %SIG;
```

Using `$Config{sig_name}/$Config{sig_num}` is the only portable way to map signal numbers to names, but a quick and dirty way that works on many Unix-y systems is

```
$sig_name = qx(kill -l $sig_num);
```

(`$sig_name` will then have a trailing newline, so in practice you'd want to do something like

```
chomp($sig_name = qx(kill -l $sig_num));
($sig_name) = qx(kill -l $sig_num) =~ /(\S+)/;
```

)

That's not necessarily any more concise than using `%Config`, though, unless you turned it into a function.

```
sub sig_no { chomp(my ($sig_no = qx(kill -l $_[0])); $sig_no }

$SIG{ sig_no($ret & 127) } = 'DEFAULT';
...
```

Comment: I'm dubious of the "keys %SIG" technique. A reasonably recent Perl (5.12.4) recommends going to $Config{sig_name}, and I believe it's because historically you couldn't count on Perl to populate %SIG with signals you hadn't personally set.  It appears in practice that 5.12.4 on Linux does populate the keys, but it's not clear that that is portable across systems or versions of Perl.